# Small confusion about convergence test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{10+n}$ either converges or diverges.

The first thing that I noticed is that it looks like the divergent harmonic series. First I did the nth term divergence test, which turned out to be inconclusive.

Then, because of the aforementioned harmonic series, I thought I'd do a comparison test. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{10+n}$, and we know the harmonic series diverges, well then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{10+n}$ diverges. Now, here's the thing:

I could write $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{10+n}$ as $5\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10+n}$, but $\frac{1}{n} \nleq \frac{1}{10+n}$. However, $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{5}{10+n}$, but only from $n \geq 3$.

Here's what I don't know what to do:In all the examples I've seen, $n$ is always $\geq 1$, and there is no mention if it matters if you start your $n$ from somewhere else.

Second thing is, it is easy to see that $\frac{1}{n} \nleq \frac{1}{10+n}$, since a bigger denominator means a smaller number. However, with $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{5}{10+n}$ it isn't that easy to see. How could I proof it is so, from $n \geq 3$?

Third option ;-): Just do a limit comparison test!

Comment: You can do the limit comparison test or the integral test.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I went for in the end, the limit comparison test. Just wondered if I should bother figuring it out for the comparison test.

Comment: Leaving out the factor $5$ (which is irrelevant for convergence), you can add to the series the terms $1+1/2+\dots+1/10$ and …

Comment: Let $n$ be positive. Then $1/n \le 5/(10+n) \Leftrightarrow 10+n \le 5n \Leftrightarrow 10 \le 4n \Leftrightarrow 5/2 \le n$.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi By the way, the question shows clearly that you work on the question of the convergence before asking here a question. Thank you. But you don't clearly (in my opinion) state what is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct comparison test (my personal favorite when I can make it work).  One thing to keep in mind is that the inequality does not have to be true for all $n$, just the entire "tail" of the series.  This is because the first finitely many terms always sum to something finite.  It only matters what happens for all $n\geq N$ (you can specify $N$ to be any finite number you like).

You could do a direct comparison like this (so that the inequality is easy to see):  Keep in mind that $\displaystyle C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges for any $C>0$, in this case, I will pick $C=\frac{1}{11}$.

$$\frac{1}{11}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{11n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+10}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5}{n+10}.$$

Note that $11n \geq n+10$ since $n\geq 1$ and smaller denominator (same numerator) means bigger fraction.

An alternative might be this:  Notice that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+10}$ is the same as $\displaystyle \sum_{n=11}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$.  Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{1}{n}$ is finite and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is infinite, you may conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=11}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is also infinite (otherwise, the sum of two finite numbers cannot be infinite).

Answer (score 1):

Another type of comparison test shows that

$\frac{ \frac{1}{n} }{\frac{5}{10+n}} \to \frac{1}{5}$(const.) as $n\to \infty$ and $\sum^\infty \frac{1}{n}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ implies $\sum^\infty \frac{5}{10 + n}$ diverges.

Comment: This looks like the limit comparison test (although there, $\frac{1}{n}$ would be the denominator). Yeah, this works too.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the property $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ra_n=r\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is applied only when the given series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is converge, so it does not make sense when you write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{10+n}$ as $5.\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10+n}$.

Comment: I was not aware of that. So, in essence, I always compare to $\frac{5}{10+n}$ instead of $\frac{1}{10+n}$.

Answer (score 0):

EVERY series either converges or diverges, so there's nothing to prove here... Equivalently, the proof is straightforward.

However if you have to *determine* whether the series converges or diverges *and* prove that, I would suggest to substitute $k=10+n$ and look at the resulting series $$\sum\limits_{k=11}^{\infty}\frac5k$$ which is $$\sum\limits_{k=11}^{\infty}\frac5k = 5\sum\limits_{k=11}^{\infty}\frac1k = 5\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}\frac1k\right)$$